# I am having an error when installing expo using install expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo

when i install expo using expo-cli i get this error with thousands of errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuEJJ.png)

Please help

Comment: What error do you mean? All I see is warnings in your screenshot.

Comment: None of the errors in your screenshot should halt running the application in the simulator. Is the installation successful? If so, ignore errors.